# XML XInclude and two elements with the same name

Tags: xml, xinclude

I have two different XML files (IzPack installation to be exact) which a common part. Naturally, I would like to keep this common part in one (external) file and to include it into two XML installation files.

I cannot make it work as it appears that XInclude can only include files with XML elements. To illustrate the example, here is some code:

File 1:

```
<packs>
 <pack name="1">
 ...
 </pack>
 <pack name="2">
 ...
 </pack>
<packs>
```

File 2:

```
<packs>
 <pack name="1">
 ...
 </pack>
 <pack name="2">
 ...
 </pack>
 <pack name="3">
 ...
 </pack>
<packs>
```

I would like the included file to contain only

```
 <pack name="1">
 ...
 </pack>
 <pack name="2">
 ...
 </pack>
```

But it looks like it's impossible. What am I missing ?

Update:
The Xinclude code looks like:

```
<packs>  
  <xi:include xmlns:xi="w3.org/2001/XInclude"; href="browserPacks.xml" parse="text"/>
```

Comment: Isn't it what parse="text" XInclude parameter is for ?

Comment: @Demiurg: yes, that's what it should be for. What does your XML with the xinclude look like??

Comment: <packs>
 <xi:include xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" href="browserPacks.xml" parse="text"/>
 </packs>

Comment: @Demiurg: in these comments, you can't really format anythign nicely - please update your original question, rather than putting stuff like XML here into comments - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How does your `xinclude` look like? Have you tried `parse=text`:

```
 <xi:include href="common.xml" parse="text"
      xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"/>
```

So with this, you *should* be able to have your file1 look like this:

```
<packs>
   <xi:include href="common.xml" parse="text"
          xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"/>
<packs>
```

and your file2 like this:

```
<packs>
   <xi:include href="common.xml" parse="text"
          xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"/>
   <pack name="3">
      ....
   </pack>
<packs>
```

Comment: Yes, I tried parse="text" - no luck. 

I'm starting to think that it's a bug in IzPack, although it uses javax.xml